# Excel - Using Two Data Tables to Build Output Table

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, array

I am trying to compare the locations of numbers in two different data tables and create an output summing the total revenue booked per day of the week based off the location of the day of the week in Table 1 and the corresponding rate paid for that day of the week in Table 2.

In Table 1: C16:H25, we have which day of the week someone booked at one of our rental properties (4 = Wednesday, 5 = Thursday, etc.).

In Table 2: J16:O25, we have the rate that person paid for that corresponding day in table 1.

I am trying to sum the total paid by each party in the Output Table C3:J6.

So, basically, if in Table 1, C18 & C19 both equal 4, then look into Table 2 and find the rates paid for by those guests on that day (J18 and J19) and sum that up into the Output Table in G6 for Wednesday.  So on and so forth for the entire Output Table.

Hope this makes sense.

[image]

Comment: Unless you need all 3 tables visible at the same time, I'd suggest putting them on different tabs/sheets. This will help you keep them organized as well as making them more printer and presentation friendly, if you ever end up needing to do that.

Answer (score 0):

**SUMPRODUCT based on Criteria can solve the issue:**

[image]

- Formula in Cell `T6`, fill it Right.

`=SUMPRODUCT(($M$4:$R$11=T$4)*($M$16:$R$23))`

*You may adjust cell references as needed.*